# В чем ошибка в программе вычисления выражений? Вместо результата выводит nan

Tags: java, c++, c, nan

Нужно сделать программу, которая выводит результат вычисления выражения в консоль. Проблема в том, что результат выводится корректно, если присвоить значения переменным в коде программы. Но если ввести их с клавиатуры, то выводит `nan`. Код на Java.
Как исправить ошибку и сделать две такие же программы на C и C++ ?

```
    package Formula;
    import static java.lang.Math.pow;
    import java.util.Scanner;




    public class My_Program {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double m, a, res, s1, e, l1, s2, mod1, mod2, l2;
        System.out.println("Введите целое число х:");
        Scanner in= new Scanner (System.in);
        int x = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Введите целое число d:");
        int d = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Введите дробное число a. Целую и дробную часть разделите запятой:");
        a = in.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Введите дробное число u. Целую и дробную часть разделите запятой:");
        m = in.nextDouble();

        s1= Math.pow(Math.sin( pow(d,3)),2);
        e=Math.exp(Math.abs(a-Math.tan(x)));
        mod1=Math.abs((1-s1)/(1.5+e));

        l1=pow(Math.log(pow(a,2)),3);
        s2=pow(Math.sin(d),2);
        mod2=Math.abs((m-l1)/(1+s2));
        l2=pow(Math.log(mod2)/Math.log(3),2);

        res=Math.acos (pow( mod1,0.3333)+Math.sqrt(2.7+l2));


        System.out.print("Входные данные \r\n");
        System.out.print("============== \r\n");
        System.out.printf("a =%.1f",a);
        System.out.print( "\r\n");
        System.out.printf("d = %d ",d);
        System.out.print( "\r\n");
        System.out.printf("x = %d",x);
        System.out.print( "\r\n");
        System.out.printf("U=%f",m);
        System.out.print("\r\n");
        System.out.print("Результат:\r\n");
        System.out.print("==============");
        System.out.print( "\r\n");
        System.out.printf("B= %f",res);
    }
}
```

Comment: Какие данные вводите при выполнении программы?

Comment: Х=22 а=1,4 , U= 14,9 d=7

Answer (score 1):

В документации Math.acos написано:

> If the argument is NaN or its absolute value is greater than 1, then the result is NaN.

В вашем случае, Вы пытаетесь вычислить арккосинус числа, которое больше единицы и получаете в ответе NaN

Если присвоить значения переменным в коде программы, тоже будет выводиться NaN, попробуйте вместо определения переменных через nextInt(), определить их в коде программы так:

```
int x = 22;
int d = 7;
double a = 1.4;
double m = 14.9;
```

Comment: Нашел ошибку. Правильная формула результата res=Math.acos (pow( mod1,0.3333))+Math.sqrt((2.7+l2)); Вопрос в следующем в Java ответ 3,7 с++ = 2,7. Почему не совпадают ответы?

Comment: у меня в java результат 2,687 - близко к тому что у вас в с++

Comment: Какая у Вас среда разработки? Я работаю в IJ IDEA. Я всю голову себе уже сломал.

Comment: результат не должен зависеть от среды разработки, пример запускаю на IJ IDEA (c JRE 1.8)

Comment: Можно Ваш код посмотреть? Тут можно прикреплять изображения? Я Вам скриншот хочу скинуть. Что за магия?

Comment: Приношу извинения, сейчас у меня тоже 3,7. У меня неправильно была определена переменная m

Comment: Вернемся к первому вопросу: почему в разных программах разные ответы?

Comment: сложно сказать, неизвестно что у вас написано на с++, я бы посоветовал, разделить вычисление на составные части, и понять в каком именно месте (на каком шаге) происходит расхождения.

Comment: Спасибо. Сейчас попробую.